# Linux mint 'apt list' doesn't work with packages starting with W

Tags: linux-mint, terminal, apt, wildcards

I am pretty new to Linux. I have **Linux Mint 19.3** installed. So basically as I understand `apt list` works with wildcards like `*` and `?`. It works fine with most other letters and letter sequences I had tried. But when I wanted to list all **Wine** packages installed, I found out that my `apt list` doesn't work with all combinations of letters of word "wine" and wildcards. For example: it doesn't work with "w*, wi*, win*, wine* etc". And I have other packages except wine starting with letter W. It only lists package with exact same names stated. However it seems to work when I use quotes (my **apt** version is < 2.0 so it seems like it treats asterisks in quotes as wildcards as well). Am I missing something, is it a bug or something else?

**Edit 0**: So thanks to the comments I figured out that it is because there are files in the directory the terminal was started in that start with W. But why is this and how does this work on programming level? Isn't it supposed to treat all other arguments as command's options other than filenames?

Comment: In the directory where you're running this, do you have any files that start with w, wi, etc?  If so, `w*`, `wi*` etc. will expand to that filename.  Try quoting: `'w*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `bash` wildcard like `w*`, `bash` gets the first go at searching for matching entries in the directory and passes them onto `apt` before `apt` has a chance to evaluate it, otherwise commands like `ls file*` would not work. Using quotation marks forces `bash` to interpret the expression literally, and the wildcard gets passed onto the command for evaluation. You could alternatively use regex `apt list --installed | grep ^w.*`, which bash does not evaluate.

Comment: I’ll take your `grep ^w.*`, and raise you a `touch ^w.` ;-). Bash does evalute the glob there too...

Comment: `apt list` already permits patterns. There's no need to invoke `grep`. Use `apt list --installed 'w*'`.